# Extract digits in between 2 different parameters

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have all data being imported into one cell as:

```
"<blank space><email address><blank space><CustomerId><blank space><(email address)><line break for next entry>"
```

Example:

> email1@provider.com 12345678 (email1@provider.com)
> email224@provider.com 23902490 (email224@provider.com)

I need to extract only the customer ID's, while separating them with a comma, so I tried the following: `regexreplace(A2,"([^[:digit:]])",",")`, however, this also extracts the numbers associated with the emails, so it returns me:

> ,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,12345678,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
> ,,,,,224,,,,,,,,,,,,,,23902490,,,,,,,224,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Since the email address is set by the user, I don't have control how many digits or if only digits are used in it. I can't seem to understand how to isolate the CustomerIds alone.

Please help!

Edit1:
CustomerID: 64-bit int field, randomly assigned to a client, therefore checking by the length of the string would not work.

Edit2:
For now, I am using the formula below, but I would still be interested in a solution using Regex.

```
filter(transpose(split($B$4," ")),isnumber(transpose(split($B$4," "))))
```

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(col, "(?s).*?(\d{8})(?:\s*\([^()]*\)$)?", "$1,")`

Comment: Nice!
I should have said in the question: CustomerID is 64-bit int field, which is arbitrarily assigned to customers, and the only requirement is to be greater than 0. 
Would there be a way to check without attributing a length to the CustomerID?

Comment: See the answer below, just use `=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2, "\b(\d+)\b"))))`

Answer (score 0):

If they are separated by a space you should be able to set the space to be your delimiter and extract from there.

https://zapier.com/blog/split-text-excel-zapier/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this as a solution: filter(transpose(split($B$4," ")),isnumber(transpose(split($B$4," ")))).

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A2, "(?s)(\d{8})"))))
```

[image]

Comment: `(?s)` is only necessary when your pattern contains a `.` to make it match any characters including line break characters. Here, since the pattern contains no `.` the `(?s)` inline modifier is redundant.